# Problems with running a SSIS package processing a tabular cube on azure on a virtual machine

Tags: ssis, ssas-tabular, data-gateway

I need some help here. I have published my datawarehouse database and ssis packages  to a virtual machine on azure. the SSAS is in azure analysis services, and the ssis package will process the cube. I have set up an on-premise datagateway that is running on azure. Everything seems ok but when the analysis services Processing task runs it stops and returning this error:

Error: The JSON DDL request failed with the following error: Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'An error occurred during On-Premise Gateway related activity.
Additional error details:
DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_InvalidConnectionCredentials Reveiced error payload from gateway service....

Below it says Missing or invalid credentials for data source. AccessUnauthorized.

I believe this error has something to do with the credentials on accessing the datawarehouse during processing the tabular cube. But I am really lost here, how to correct this error from SSIS parameters.

Do any of you had this same problem and has solved it please let me know how you solved and the cause of this issue.

Hope to hear from you really soon

regards geir